# Excel round 0.34 to 0.35

Tags: microsoft-excel, wps-spreadsheet

Let say A1's value is `0.34`

If I use `=ROUND(A1,2)` formula in excel, this will produce `0.34` too.

I know this is the right one.

What I want to do is to change `0.34` value to `0.35`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Excel provides three functions for round numbers to the nearest multiple
of 0.5:

- To round a number down to nearest 0.5, use the **FLOOR** function, for example
  *=FLOOR(A2, 0.5)*.
- To round a number up to nearest 0.5, use the **CEILING** function, for example
  *=CEILING(A2, 0.5)*.
- To round a number up or down to nearest 0.5, use the **MROUND** function,
  for example *=MROUND(A2, 0.5)*. Rounding up or down depends on the remainder from
  dividing the number by multiple - if the remainder is equal to or greater than
  half the value of multiple, the number is rounded upward, otherwise downward.

[image]

[source](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/08/06/excel-round-functions/#Round-to-nearest-0.5)

Comment: interesting.  Seems Mround only works for positive values.

Comment: If negatives involved, try instead =MROUND($A3, SIGN($A3) * 0.5)

Answer (score 4):

Use `=ROUND(A1*2,1)/2` or `=MROUND(A1,.05)`. This lets you round in .05 increments.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. I'm still getting `0.34`